# how to grep output from windows command line

Tags: regex, cmd, grep, windows-10

I use windows command prompt cmd in admin mode for various task like finding ip address interface names etc. When I issue some command like 
ipconfig /all

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : 
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : domain.name

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.name
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 10 December 2019 22:10:04
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 11 December 2019 03:10:04
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 33574998
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.136.1(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 10 December 2019 22:10:04
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 11 December 2019 03:10:04
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.136.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 268456022
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.136.2
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.name
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : D-Link DWA-131 Wireless N Nano USB Adapter(rev.E)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.14(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 10 December 2019 22:10:09
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 11 December 2019 22:10:12
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
                                       192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 353154770
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 109.169.85.7
                                       8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.name
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

I get a lot of output on my screen.If I want only those lines which have physical addeess in
text output or say line that have DNS Servers only in ouput. Then is there an easy way to do 
a grep on these in outout in Windows 10 cmd.
Or suppose in above output I want to see only output for section Vmnet8

then how can I grep it?

Comment: Type `findstr /?`. See https://pastebin.com/nkkCUMKn.

Comment: I download the pastebin there were no lines that begin with findstr /? ok I think you mean to try output with findstr I tried `ipconfig /all | findstr /C:Physical Address
FINDSTR: Cannot open address` does piping even exist in Windows

Comment: The pastebin article tells you it does. You need to enclose things with spaces in double quotes. `ipconfig /all | findstr /C:"127.0.0.1"`. Your command without quotes tells findstr to open file `address` (rather than StdIn) and show lines containing `physical`.

Comment: oh thanks I did not understood the article yes I tried what you said it worked.You mentioned the command without quotes tells findstr to open file address I want to read more about it please give some link.Please give more pastebin links or cheatsheets if you have.

Comment: There is a million of them. The rule is __parameters with spaces must be enclosed in quotes__. Quotes are optional if there are no spaces. So your search term is `physical` because that is where the space is that ends it (if not in quotes). According to `Findstr /?` the next parameter is the input file (if specified).

Comment: Read the Pastebin article's section towards the bottom on how to access Help at the command line.

Comment: Does it have to be grep?  Can it be powershell? I don't understand what you want. Using the sample output you posted put an example of each thing you want in the question.

Comment: I am not familiar with powershell , i am a linux guy so asked it in linux kind of word grep, grep is a Linux command line utility to find particular lines in command output which comes from issuing command in previous step and piping combines it do do in a single line.I have no idea of windows command lines. I have got the answer in above paste bin links when i read findstr /? Help on windows command line. And usage of &,&&,| in Windows command in pastebin link clearly told the way to so .

Comment: When Microsoft bought Dos 1 to sell to IBM they were the leading supplier of OEM Unix systems. Dos 1 was based on CP/M micro processor OS. The first thing Microsoft's Unix programmers did was add as many Unix features to Dos as they had room for. This is where handles were introduced and also redirection and piping. Computer magazines at the time told us piping is the way of the future. We would edit our DTP documents (at a command prompt?), pipe it to the spell checker, then to the grammar checker, then to the print program. It's been 36 years and I'm still waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the free MOBAXTERM then navigate through your windows OS same as if you are using Linux. Then you will be able to use grep etc.

Answer (score 6):

> I want only those lines which have physical addeess

```
ipconfig|findstr /r ":: [0-9]\."
```

filters for lines that contain `::` (for IPv6 addresses) or `<number><dot>` (for IPv4 addresses)

(as you mentioned being a "Linux-Guy" - don't expect too much from `findstr` REGEX. It's just a small crippled subset of real REGEX - see `findstr /?`)

Answer (score 0):

With the introduction of **[Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)** (`WSL`), you can use `grep` directly on `ipconfig`.

** *I have limited knowledge* on `grep`. Here is a basic example usage:

1. On the classic Windows **Command Prompt**, run:

   `C:\> ipconfig /all | wsl grep 'IPv4'`
2. On a **Linux Terminal** (*e.g. Ubuntu on WSL*), run (notice the `.exe` extension):

   `$ ipconfig.exe /all | grep 'IPv4'`

#### Sample output

```
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.198.100.1(Preferred)
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.198.15.9(Preferred)
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.198.89.1(Preferred)
 ...
```

Comment: Using WSL2, you might want to use the option `-all` instead of '/all' for `ipconfig.exe` as the latter in interpreted as a Binary format